# Regular expression to extract text between multiple hyphens

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string in the following format

----------some text-------------

How do I extract "some text" without the hyphens?
I have tried with this but it matches the whole string

```
(?<=-).*(?=-)
```

Comment: Did any of the posted answers work out?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern matches the whole line except the first and last hyphen due to the assertions on the left and right and the `.` also matches a hyphen.

You can keep using the assertions, and match any char except a hyphen using `[^-]+` which is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
(?<=-)[^-]+(?=-)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hb1QQ3/1).

Note: if you also want to prevent matching a newline you can use `(?<=-)[^-\r\n]+(?=-)`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following regex.

```
^-+([^-]*)-+$
```

[Online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O64GNS/2)

***Explanation:*** Matching all dashes from starting 1 or more occurrences then creating one and only capturing group which has everything matched till next `-` comes, then matching all dashes till last of value.

Comment: @praveen, could you please do let me know if this solution has helped you?

Comment: If the text in the middle has a dash or multiple dashes, it doest work...

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python, right? Then you do not need regex.

Use

```py
s = "----------some text-------------"
print(s.strip("-"))
```

**Results**: `some text`.

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBVkFJFw6K83NTFUpSK0p0kYESV0FRZl6JRrFecUlRZoGGkq6Spub//wA).

With regex, the same can be achieved using

```py
re.sub(r'^-+|-+$', '', s)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/pvkYv5/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -+                       '-' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -+                       '-' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```